# How to Add member in Facebook App Group using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I am trying to Add member in Facebook App Group using post method.but no success

```
FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient();

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

parameters.access_token = access_token;// Session["AccessToken"];

parameters.member = "56765471405943";

dynamic  result = app.Post("/45645620480560/members",parameters);
```

it's showing error.

Comment: What error do you obtain?

Comment: An exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookOAuthException' occurred in Facebook.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: (OAuthException - #4002) (#4002) The attempt to invite the user to the group failed.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307885/how-do-i-create-facebook-app-group-using-facebook-csharp-sdk-or-js-sdk